# How to add clone of a java object to list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist and I want to add some objects with little changes to this arraylist.

Here is my code;

```
Student student = createSampleStudent();
List<Student> studentList= new ArrayList<Student>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student.setId(getRandomId());
    studentList.add(student);
}
```

I want to add students to studentList with different ids.I can't create student in for loop because it takes too long to create a student. I have found that there is a clone method but Student object has many fields(most of them refers to another object). Is there any idea?

Comment: Clone is a dangerous method, use with caution. Either way I don't believe it will be any quicker than creating new students in a loop (which is the correct thing to do)

Comment: p.s. why in gods name does it take a long time to create a student?! What is happening within students constructor?

Comment: @RichardTingle some webservice methods are running. It is not about my code actually but it takes about 30 seconds. So I don't want to create Student everytime.

Comment: Do your students have some shared data internally? If so whatever is slow could be created once and then passed as an argument in the students constructor

Comment: @RichardTingle I am getting student objects from webservice. Student constructor has 11 parameters and most of them are objects. I think calling createSampleStudent method everytime is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I just tell you a creepy method to copy object, you must not use it in production code, but I think it will be work. You can use Unsafe, the Sun's backdoor. All that you need to do is get Unsafe instance:

```
Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
f.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
```

Ignore your IDE, it will warn you about access restriction, but if you run this code everything will work. If the error is annoying, ignore errors in preferences. After this you can do a copy of object on low-level memory copying.

```
private static long normalize(int value) {
    if(value >= 0) return value;
    return (~0L >>> 32) & value;
}

public static long sizeOf(Object object){
    return getUnsafe().getAddress(
        normalize(getUnsafe().getInt(object, 4L)) + 12L);
}

private static long toAddress(Object obj) {
    Object[] array = new Object[] {obj};
    long baseOffset = getUnsafe().arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
    return normalize(getUnsafe().getInt(array, baseOffset));
}

private static Object fromAddress(long address) {
    Object[] array = new Object[] {null};
    long baseOffset = getUnsafe().arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
    getUnsafe().putLong(array, baseOffset, address);
    return array[0];
}

static Object shallowCopy(Object obj) {
    long size = sizeOf(obj);
    long start = toAddress(obj);
    long address = getUnsafe().allocateMemory(size);
    getUnsafe().copyMemory(start, address, size);
    return fromAddress(address);
}
```

After all you can just call in your for loop this construction:

```
Student student = createSampleStudent();
List<Student> studentList= new ArrayList<Student>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student = MyUnsafeUtil.shallowCopy(student);
    student.setId(getRandomId());
    studentList.add(student);
}
```

Remember, this is a really bad and dark magic in java.